# Float issue with IE6 (without any margins / paddings)

Tags: css, css-float, internet-explorer-6

I'm trying to get a website I've made to show correctly in my favorite browser ever that never gives me hassles - IE6 !!! lol.
I've got 2 floated elements within a div:

```
#content_container { position:relative; width: 908px; background-color:#FFFFFF; padding: 26px; min-height:400px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#545454; }
#content_container_left { position:relative; width: 384px; float:left;}
#content_container_right { position:relative; width: 496px; float:right; text-align:justify;}
```

The CSS above results in this:

[image]

as you can see the text (#content_container_right) information is below the gallery (#content_container_left) where as the right container SHOULD float on the right where the empty space is.

I've tried giving `margin:0px;` and `padding:0px;` to both floating elements but this doesn't work ... and although I don't have any margins in my floating elements `display:inline;` doesn't work either.
The padding in the parent div doesn't seem to be the issue.

BTW: I have been testing this in [IE Tester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) which has proved to be EXTREMELY useful (even though it may not be 100% replica of the real trash)

Any Ideas / suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us your html too?

Comment: ..and you should balance how long this is taking you against the number of people who will actually be using a deprecated and increasingly obscure browser!

Comment: I know!!! I have received some visits with people STILL on IE6 and IE5.5 (shame on them) .. but this is also something I want to learn and understand, I'll update with HTML

Comment: My HTML is too large ... though I've just figured out that a div containing a form within the right container is causing the issue. I will do some research to see why it's doing this and follow up on here

Comment: I respect the ambition to learn how to solve this, kudos to that. However, since even Microsoft themselves have retired IE6, to keep adjusting websites to work well in IE6 actually makes more damage than good. I would recommend a friendly message to the users about why they should upgrade their browser (see example by 37Signals below). This gives them a much needed push to upgrade, saves you a lot of time and helps the overall web development community evolve.

http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3097-developing-for-old-browsers-is-almost-a-thing-of-the-past

Comment: @MSchumacher also, if you used `display:inline` you would have to use `zoom:1` in IE6 to make it an inline-block, and replicate the effect you're going for. Even if that doesn't fix your problem, you should probably know that.

Comment: @henrik: I totally agree with you and I have done that (upgrade message) with a very large website that I'm not going to sweat all day to work in IE6.

Comment: @ohgodwhy ... I've have tried zoom and inline and that didn't work, though as mentioned above I've found the problem div that contains a form which has floated elements within that's causing the issue. I will revert back though for people who are experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @MSchumacher floated elements within forms need `display:inline` in IE6. Also, are your floats being cleared? Are you conforming to box-model principles?

Comment: Yes I have cleared the float, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I've figured it out that the `display:inline;`  and `zoom:1` has solved my issues (use them in the floated divs). The guys below have given some great advice regarding IE6. Remember not to break your back for IE6 as Henrik mentions, because this just makes Microsoft LAZY and it is fading out.